# Plotting orbits TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python

I'm given a problem where a satellite is orbiting the earth at an altitude of p = 15000km from the center of the Earth. I need to create a table of the height of the satellite from the surface of the Earth versus theta from 0 - 360 in increments of 30 degrees using the equation r = p/1-e*cos(theta), where e represents eccentricity, p is 15000 km. I'm given e = 0, 0.2, 0.7. Doing the below results in a float error. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to plot a list of numbers for theta with integers, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
pi = 3.14159 
eccentricity = 0
theta = pi/6, pi/4, pi/3, pi/2, 2*pi/3, 3*pi/4, 5*pi/6, pi, 7*pi/6, 5*pi/4, 4*pi/3, 3*pi/2, 5*pi/3, 7*pi/4, 11*pi/6, 2*pi
p = 8629 #15000 - radius of Earth in km

def r(eccentricity, p, theta):
    return p/(1-eccentricity*math.cos(theta))

print r(eccentricity, p, theta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `theta` is a tuple of floats, you cannot pass it to a function that expects a single float.

You have two options:

compute heights using a list comprehension:

```
heights = [r(eccentricity, p, th) for th in theta]
```

use `numpy` which allows to work with arrays directly

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.array(theta)
heights = r(eccentricity, p, theta)
```

**Edit:**
Since you are using numpy, you can simplify your `theta` array with

```
theta = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I tried the second option but this resulted in a TypeError saying only size-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars. All I changed was add a new variable defining theta as = np.array(theta).

Comment: Right, replace `math.cos` with `np.cos`.